# Detect page is fully loaded using requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, loaded

I want to know if there is a response from `requests.get(url)` when the page is fully loaded. I did tests with around 200 refreshes of my page and it happens randomly that once or twice the page does not load the footer.

Answer (score 0):

First requests GET will return you the entire page but requests is no a browser, it does not parse the content.
When you load a page with the browser, it does usually 10-50 requests for each resource, runs the JavaScript, ....

Comment: Yes you're right, I will add another condition on html returned to check the entire page. Thanks.